# Pass flags to docker in Azure aci

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have a container image (rancher/rancher:latest) that I need to pass "--acme-domain=" flag.
How can this be done in Azure Aci?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error I was able to do this using the command parameter in the [Azure Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/2018-10-01/containergroups). The gist of it was that I had to explicitly call the container entry point, e.g. `"command":["./scripts/entry","--acme-domain=foo"]`. I suppose you could do the same with the `--command-line` argument in the Azure CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set an environment variable for your tag "--acme-domain=" in Azure ACI.

For more details, see [Set environment variables in Azure ACI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried that and I think turns out that Aci does not support environment variables starting with "--".  In my case however the binary running in the container (rancher/rancher) needs the flag passed as a command line argument and will not read it from the environment.

Comment: @JMan If you want to execute a command in the ACI, you can use the CLI command [`az container exec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-exec).

Comment: What I want to do is the equivalent of "docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 rancher/rancher:latest --acme-domain rancher.yourdomain.com"

Comment: Does it a bash command? If it is, you can set it with a parameter `--command-line` for the command [`az container create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create).

Comment: This is what the entry point looks like https://github.com/rancher/rancher/blob/master/package/entrypoint.sh

Comment: But shouldn't Aci allow me to start the image the same way docker allows me to do it? Seems odd that I would have to dig in the inner workings of an image.

Comment: Yeah, it should be. But it seems that it does not support all docker parameters on ACI. Maybe it will support in the future.